# If Pentaho is Open Source, can I just use it?

Tags: open-source, pentaho

I see that [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) wants to charge me for their software. How can I get to the underlying Open Source software for dashboards to see what it can do without having to deal with Pentaho marketing folks?

Answer (score 20):

Most commercial open source editions have a community edition that the community hacks on **if the license permits it***. Pentaho is no different from them and has a [community edition](http://community.pentaho.com/).

In these cases, the "community edition" is not the same thing as the commercial product you would buy. You may find a lot of the gloss and even some, if not a lot of the features are missing. There's no support. Yadda yadda yadda. You get the picture.

*As others have noted, not all "open source" apps need to distribute the source code in the same way as, a GPL application would. Open source, in rawest forms, just means as a licensed user, you get to see the source code.

Answer (score 12):

Just to provide detail on what pentaho do and dont provide - they do provide a very complete BI platform as part of the community edition.

The only things that the enterprise edition include are a web based dashboard designer and a few other bits and bobs - i.e. not very much at all.

As mentioned above the benefit to becoming a subscription customer with pentaho is that they provide support, which for us was very useful in our final implementation.

Check out their forums too though - they are very active, and as long as your questions arnt complete newbie ones they are very helpful too.  I sometimes use the forums despite having a support agreement as i know it can be quicker.

Answer (score 6):

"Open source" is not the same thing as "free" (either "as in beer" or "as in speech").

As much as I'm not a fan of Stallman in general, this article will probably help clear up the distictions a bit: [Why "Open Source" misses the point of Free Software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.html)

Comment: free speech isn't even as free as people tend to think it is. woo! off-topic political discussion!

Comment: You can't say that here! This isn't a designated Free Speech Zone!

Answer (score 3):

Open Source != Free

IANAL, but I'd say you're bound to the license that the software is under.

Answer (score 3):

Suds get your free download of the code from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/

They have an IRC chat channel as well that ive found to be extremely helpful.